# How to replace an observation in a attribute table using if-then conditional statement in ARC GIS Pro

Tags: field, arcgis

I have an attribute table with a column that has many observations below a chemical detection limit - 0.005. Since these are not valid measurements, I would like to replace all values in the field under 0.005 with the value 0.0025. So: if observation < 0.005 then replace with 0.0025.

I am not familiar with python coding but using calculate field I have tried (unsuccessfully) to reclassify values to another value using:

```
def Reclass(arg):
if arg is < 0.005:
    return 0.0025
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Choose Python in the dropdown:

```
def r(fld):
if fld is None or fld >= 0.005:
    return fld
elif fld < 0.005:
    return 0.0025
```